# GET request gives Connection refused

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, resttemplate, wso2-api-manager

I have following CURL command which works fine using -k options, which means: insecure, Allow connections to SSL sites without certs.

I am using `WSO2 API Manager` tool version `1.9.1`.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=test&password=test" -H 
     "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
      Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
      https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8243/token
```

Now I wanted to achieve the same using the RestTemplate in Spring, so I developed the following code so far, and it's giving me a *Connection refused* error:

My Code

```
@Before
public void testBefore(){
    disableSslVerification();
}

private static void disableSslVerification() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

@Test
    public void testGetTokenFromWSo2(){
        String url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX:8243/token";

```
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("grant_type", "password");
    map.add("username", "test");
    map.add("password", "test");

    HttpHeaders headers =new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, map);
    System.out.println("RESPONSE : "+response.getBody());
}
```

The error I see

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:8243/token":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:463)
```

Comment: Clear from the message that your oauth is not running on `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:8243`

Comment: I edited your question giving it a more readable title, and also improved some code formatting and indenting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolved this error. We can connect to `SSL protected site` by `insecure` way i.e, connecting to `SSL sites without verifying cert`. You can find the solution here and it works fine [java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841899/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present).