# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present;

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager

I am using `WSO2 API Manager` version `1.9.1`. In this tool, I publish my sample project (i.e., `proxied`) and subscribe that project to get consumer key and secret. This tool also gives me CURL command which works fine.

The below CURL command which runs fine.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX" -H "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/token
```

Now I'm trying to developed the `java` code using `RestTemplate` which will connect to `SSL protected site` without `cert verification` i.e., `insecure` way looking at above CURL command.
So far I developed below code, but when I run I see following error coming.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.toString());
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        String url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/token";

        String data = "grant_type=password&username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(data,headers);
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("RESPONSE : "+response.getBody());
    }
```

The error I am facing. **Please suggest how we can connect to SSL site insecure way, the same curl command does?**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://XXXXXXXXXXX:8243/token":java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
    at com.java.wso2.TokenDemo.main(TokenDemo.java:74)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 3 more
```

How we can solve this error? Off-course my issue is not similar to [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167691/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no)

Comment: There was an answer posted here that many people seemed to find useful. Unfortunately, it was plagiarized with insufficient attribution, so it had to be deleted. The source it copied from was: https://nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/

Answer (score 2):

[API Manager 1.9.1 Support EOL Date](https://wso2.com/products/support-matrix/) was Aug 31, 2019, so if you haven't I strongly suggest you update to the latest version.

Normally you'll want to use http if you want the insecure address. In WSO2 https is configured to be secure and you can import the backend client certificate into the client trust store file using these the directions on [Adding SSL Certificates to keystrokes](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/importing_ssl_certificate/https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/importing_ssl_certificate/) page.

You may also find the [Configure Keystores](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/configuring_keystores/) page to be of assistance.

Calling an HTTPS endpoint in an insecure way can lead to security vulnerabilities and is not a best practice.

Best of luck on your adventure!